# Is there any way to create a ".exe" in linux?

Tags: linux, shell

I have a Shell Script game and i want to create the equivalent in linux of a .exe in order to share this game with my friends but without them being able to see the code. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

If your friends are just casual users, then you can use something like [shc](https://github.com/neurobin/shc) (shell script compiler). However, it's possible for skilled enough users to decompile anything that their computer can run, so you shouldn't rely on this for anything resembling real security. For example, [UnSHc](https://github.com/yanncam/UnSHc) exists, and as you might guess from its name, it can turn an shc binary back into a regular shell script.

Comment: [This link](https://www.krazyworks.com/obfuscating-shell-scripts/) might be of interest, as it shows several obfuscation techniques, including shc.